# Pandas apply discounts using equal cell values in different dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I am desperate. I am solving this problem for 3 days now. I did try all the solutions in similar posts. My solution worked on other dataframes but fails on a this one. 
I have two datasets: one contains item, regular price and discount group column. The second one - discount group and the discount of that group.
I need  take item, get a discount group, look up for discount and multiply it by price. But in some rows I get error. Here is my code:

```
for index, row in df1.iterrows():

   discount_group = df1['Discount group'][index]
   #this returns data frame with discount group and relevant discount
   discounts_df = df2.loc[df2['Discount group'] == discount_group], 'Discount'
   discount = discounts_df[0].values[0][1]
   row ['Discounted price'] = row['Price'] * discount
```

But in some cases `discounts_df = df2.loc[df2['Discount group'] == discount_group], 'Discount'` returns empty data frame. I did convert discount groups columns to float to be sure there is no type mismatch with  `df1['RG'] = df1['Discount group'].astype(float)`. It didn't help.

Maybe there is another solution?

Thanks for help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `.merge()` would be a better solution than `.iterrows()` I think. `.merge()` allows database-style joins, see [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html). Here is a toy example that applies a percentage discount (between 0 and 1) to a price column.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

facts = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        'price': np.random.randn(10),
        'discount_id': np.tile([1, 2], 5)
    }
)

discount = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        'discount_id': [1, 2],
        'discount_value': [.5, .1]
    }
)

merged = facts.merge(discount, on = 'discount_id')

# Adapt this line to apply your specific discounting logic.

merged['discounted_price'] = merged['price'] - (merged['price'] * merged['discount_value'])

print(merged)
```

Gives:

```
      price  discount_id  discount_value  discounted_price
0 -0.186169            1             0.5         -0.093084
1 -1.345143            1             0.5         -0.672572
2 -0.044090            1             0.5         -0.022045
3  0.325579            1             0.5          0.162790
4  0.794152            1             0.5          0.397076
5  1.271465            2             0.1          1.144318
6  1.041492            2             0.1          0.937342
7 -0.774214            2             0.1         -0.696793
8  0.917996            2             0.1          0.826196
9  1.055927            2             0.1          0.950334
```